# Find element in vector of pair and output c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pair:

```
typedef pair<string,int> is;
vector<is> v;
```

I push some values to the vector.

```
v.push_back(make_pair("One",1));
v.push_back(make_pair("Two",2));
v.push_back(make_pair("Three",3));
v.push_back(make_pair("Four",4));
```

I need to ask the user to input a name and search the vector , find that name and output it's corresponding int in the pair. If user types "One" I want the input to type 1.

I tried the following.

```
struct comp_pair_int
{
    bool operator()(const pair<string, int>& a, const string& b)
    {
        return (a.first < b);
    }
    bool operator()(const string& a, const pair<string, int>& b)
    {
        return (a < b.first);
    }
};
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comparison);
if (binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(),
    "One", comp_pair_int()))
    cout << "Element found\n";
else
    cout << "Element not found";
```

That code returns if the element is found or not, but that's not all I want, I also need to output the second element in the pair of the found element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) will only give you a `bool` result, so it doesn't give sufficient information to get the value of the pair you're looking for.

The idiomatic way to do this is with [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), which returns an iterator to the pair you're looking for, like this:

```
if (auto i = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(),
                              "One", comp_pair_int());
    i != v.end() && i->first == "One")   // lower bound actually found correct pair
       cout << "Element found with value " << i->second;
else
       cout << "Element not found";
```

Note that as with `binary_search` the range needs to be sorted by the same predicate you use for the search.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::find_if` if your vector is not sorted by key.
Would look like this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const is& item) {
    return item.first == user_input;
});
if(it != v.end()) {
    int my_item = it->second;
}
else {
    // key not found
}
```

Comment: Be careful, you have to take into account that `std::find_if()` returns the `end` iterator if the requested item is not found, eg: `auto it = std::find_if(...); if (it != v.end()) { int my_item = it->second; ... } else { /* do something else ... */ }`